# Inspect InAppBrowser from Chrome devTools

Tags: cordova, google-chrome-devtools, inappbrowser, inspect

Inside my Cordova mobile app i'm using inAppBrowser to open an external link.

From chrome devTools I can open and inspect my app but there's no reference to the new inAppBrowser window. 
I've tried on safari (for the iOS version of the app) and i can open a new inspector for the external page from the Develop menu.

Do you know if there's any way to achieve this on Chrome?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

The InAppBrowser window behaves like a standard web browser.
run

> chrome://inspect  (or any other supported tool

and you should inspect your InAppBrowser as a regular web browser.